# Can there be only ONE Team Agent? IOS/MAC

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, provisioning-profile

I am in biz with one partner and he set the business up with Apple.

I am now trying desperately to upload my app to them and continue to get the code sign error (Signature was invalid or it was not signed) in XCode 4.2.1 when I try and submit it.

I thought my distribution profile and cert were fine because I finally got it to Archive (which it wouldnt do)....

Ive METICULOUSLY followed every detail, check that the Code Sign is properly assigned...worked on this for nearly two whole days trying EVERYTHING.

Now Im staring at the line in the Provisioning Portal that states 'In order to distribute your iOS application, the Team Agent is required by Apple to create an iOS Distribution Certificate.'

I assumed I had all the privileges that my partner did - the archive thing started going through when I setup my provisioning cert and profile... but could this BE THE PROBLEM!?

Could it have let me do all that and only fail at the very end because I am not listed as a Team Agent?  (losing mind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there can only be one team agent and the team agent is the only person that can really distribute apps, I'm positive this is the case for AppStore and pretty sure for AdHoc

Comment: It is not true for ad hoc builds, but yes, there is only one agent and only the agent can submit to the store.

Comment: Oh MAN.. I can live with that, just wish I had been less STUPID and Apple had not allowed me to get as far as I did in the first place.  But either way, Ill be happy to have it uploaded and me being done beating my head...THANKS!